# How to find Xpath for read the list of elements use list<Webelement>

Tags: html, xpath, selenium-webdriver

webdriver finding xpath its too dificult for me. i used fire path most of fire path given xpath not working and its too lengthy. some one give me idea about xpath will work all conditions and i know relative xpath
some times this posibilities also not working like `{//ul[@class='review-nav']}`.
 some one help me for find xpath that xpath will work all conditions

```html
<ul class="review-nav">
<li id="pend" class="pend tabclass">
<a onclick="OnTabSelect(1,'pend',0)" href="#">Pending (197)</a>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter filterclass" style="color:#185daa;top:4px;display:none"/>
</li>
<li id="flag" class="flag tabclass active">
<a onclick="OnTabSelect(4,'flag',1)" href="#">Flagged (96)</a>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter filterclass" style="color:#185daa;top:4px;display:none"/>
</li>
<li id="esca" class="esca tabclass">
<a onclick="OnTabSelect(5,'esca',2)" href="#">Escalated (88)</a>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter filterclass" style="color:#185daa;top:4px;display:none"/>
</li>
<li id="closed" class="closed tabclass">
<a onclick="OnTabSelect(3,'closed',3)" href="#">Closed (99)</a>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter filterclass" style="color:#185daa;top:4px;display:none"/>
</li>
<li id="all" class="all tabclass">
<a onclick="OnTabSelect(0,'all',3)" href="#">All (1,355)</a>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter filterclass" style="color:#185daa;top:4px;display:none"/>
</li>
</ul>
```

I try this Xpath to read above list its not working

```
xpath =   //ul[@class='review-nav']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for that, I am little bit not clear for what you need xpath..

If you are trying to get all link ('a') to collect into List

```
//ul[@class='review-nav']/li/a
```

If you are trying to get all 'span' element to collect into List

```
//ul[@class='review-nav']/li/span
```

If you want to get specific element in specific li, you can try with id of 'li',  for example if you like to find xpath of 'a' in first li

```
//li[@id='pend']/a
```

Thank You

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I trying to collect (a) element in a list. I trying on that, its pòssible collect after set third element as(.click())?

Comment: @Rajkumar, if you want click on third i.e. escalated link, provided that links are static (not changing position) then use  //li[@id='esca']/a

Comment: @Rajkumar, if you want to click on third link irrespecctive of what it is, then    List<WebElement> links=  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='review-nav']/li/a"));
// click the 3rd checkbox
links.get(2).click();

Comment: Yea u correct here i trying to set random like if first time enter on loop its enter within the 4, and 2 time with inthe ffour.you have any idea about it pls share with me

Answer (score 0):

Try with CSS:

```
.tabclass
```

You should get the 'li' elements with this.